# Plugin has no US english translation file

Tags: translation, the-events-calendar

I'm trying to modify English translations for a The Events Calendar plugin but I'm not able to find the US English translation file. There is only British English. Please have a look:

[image]

Can it be that the plugin has no US translation and is directly using translation keys instead? How can I add the US translation file then?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In lack of translation file the default strings from source code are being used. So if plugin is *coded* in US english then it just has that version in source and doesn't need the translation for it.

The native way to generate translation files in WP is makepot script, shipped with development version of WordPress core. See [Using the i18n tools](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#Using_the_i18n_tools) documentation in Codex.